# Real time writing to disk

Tags: windows-7, monitoring

Is there any software out there that can help me track, in real time, files being changed and/or created on my Windows (Windows 7) system?

I'm trying to figure out all files being changed when setting up Windows Live Mail as I want to sync all relevant files between two computers. And no, the storage folder is not enough.

I'm grateful for any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Microsoft's SysInternals team should do what you need. From the site: "Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity."

Note: Process Monitor is a different utility to the excellent [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from the same authors.

Comment: You're welcome Jesper. If you think this is the best answer, please accept it as correct. :)

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend Resource Monitor which comes with Windows 7.

In the Disk tab you can view what processes are accessing the disk and what files are being accessed. You can filter the processes and sort according to criteria such as Write and Read speed etc.

[image: resource monitor observing disk changes]

This program is so useful I've mapped it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>