# Windows 7 How can I see what files are open for a given process

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm trying to understand which files a process accesses. Is there a command available for that?

Comment: This [SU answer](http://superuser.com/a/137037/50173) might help: The trick is to use Windows own resource monitor. In the disk tab you can select a process and it shows all currently touched files by this process

Answer (score 2):

You need the SysInternals suite from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062. It is not clear whether you want to see all file accesses (use Process Monitor) or check currently open files (use Process Explorer).

The link above is to the down-load page, which in turn has a link for each of the utilities, giving an overview and run parameters. You can load each individually, but you never know when you will find a need for some of the others, so I recommend taking the whole suite. They all run immediately, without any Widows installation. There is a licensing screen the first time you run each on a system.

They are a brilliant set of system utilities: I would not be without them.